# How to convert Hex to RGB? (perl)

Tags: perl, hex, rgb

How do I convert my hexidecimal colors (e.g., 0000FF, FF00FF) into arithmetic RGB format (e.g., 0 0 1, 1 0 1)?

I want to implement a command to do this in some of my perl scripts but I don't even know how to do it by hand.

Could someone please help me do this in perl or even show me how to do this by hand so I can come up with my own perl command?

Comment: @ikegami I don't know what you mean by that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to map 00..FF<sub>16</sub> to real numbers 0..1,

```
my @rgb = map $_ / 255, unpack 'C*', pack 'H*', $rgb_hex;
```

---

- `pack 'H*',` changes `"FF00FF"` to `"\xFF\x00\xFF"`.
- `unpack 'C*',` changes `"\xFF\x00\xFF"` to `0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF`.
- `map $_ / 255,` changes `0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF` to `0xFF/255, 0x00/255, 0xFF/255`

Comment: uhhh, again one write-only code - but after a while it is nearly understandable. +1 :)

Comment: This worked great. I'm not sure I understand what it is doing but that's fine. Thanks

Comment: `pack 'H*'` changes `"FF00FF"` to `"\xFF\x00\xFF"`. `unpack 'C*'` changes `"\xFF\x00\xFF"` to `0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF`. `map $_ / 255,` changes `0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF` to `0xFF/255, 0x00/255, 0xFF/255`

Comment: For a comma-delimited rgb string, suitable for CSS rgba(...):  `my $rgb = join(', ', map $_, unpack 'C*', pack 'H*', $rgb_hex);`

Answer (score 10):

There is already a CPAN module that does what you want: https://metacpan.org/pod/Color::Rgb

```
use Color::Rgb;
my $hex = '#0000FF';

my @rgb        = $rgb->hex2rgb($hex);     # returns list of 0, 0, 255
my $rgb_string = $rgb->hex2rgb($hex,','); # returns string '0,0,255'
```

It can also go the other direction:

```
my @rgb        = (0, 0, 255);              
my $hex_string = $rgb->rgb2hex(@rgb);     # returns '0000FF'
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try your method because the other one worked for me but thanks for the response.